# LLVM Global Instruction Selection failure

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to run `llc` with global instruction selection, unfortunately it fails on any shift instruction (e.g. `shl`).
Here is how to represent it using `llc -global-isel=true -filetype=asm sample.ll`:

```
define i64 @test_advance(i1 %nullify, i64 %iaoq) {
entry:
    %cache = alloca i64
    store i64 %iaoq, i64* %cache
    br i1 %nullify, label %cond_true, label %cond_false

cond_false:
    %iaoq.1 = load i64, i64* %cache
    %iaoq.2 = add i64 %iaoq.1, 4
    %iaoq.x = shl i64 %iaoq.2, 13
    store i64 %iaoq.x, i64* %cache
    br label %next_insn

cond_true:
    %iaoq.3 = load i64, i64* %cache
    %iaoq.4 = add i64 %iaoq.3, 8
    store i64 %iaoq.4, i64* %cache
    br label %after_next_insn

next_insn:
    %iaoq.5 = load i64, i64* %cache
    %iaoq.6 = add i64 %iaoq.5, 4
    store i64 %iaoq.6, i64* %cache
    br label %after_next_insn

after_next_insn:
  %res = load i64, i64* %cache
  ret i64 %res
}
```

Why is there so strange behaviour? What's so strange about shifts? My platform is x86.

**EDIT**

In release_70 this problem is solved, unfortunately global-isel can not cope with legalisation of uadd_with_overflow:

```
define i64 @test_advance(i1 %nullify, i64 %iaoq) {
entry:
    %0 = call { i64, i1 } @llvm.uadd.with.overflow.i64(i64 %iaoq, i64 %iaoq)
    %sum_64_7949 = extractvalue { i64, i1 } %0, 0
    ret i64 %sum_64_7949
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone speculatable
declare { i64, i1 } @llvm.uadd.with.overflow.i64(i64, i64) #0
```

It gets the same error:

```
LLVM ERROR: unable to legalize instruction: %3:_(s64), %4:_(s1) = G_UADDE %1:_, %1:_, %5:_ (in function: test_advance)
```

Comment: It seems like a bug(not present on svn trunk), can you update the llc version you are using?

Comment: Built from fresh release_70, this problem is solved, but new arises...